# How do I assert that an Element/Button is hidden on a page using Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to validate a scenario that for a specific user some web elements/buttons should be hidden on a page. I have done a quick-n-dirty implementation of a method to verify this and would like to know if there are better ways to do it. Please advice

```
public void ValidateThatButtonIsHidden(string button)
    {
        IWebElement theButton = null;

        if (button.ToLower().Trim() == "submit an order")
        { theButton = FindElement(By.Id(_elementBtnId1)); }

        else if (button.ToLower().Trim() == "validate order")
        { theButton = FindElement(By.Id(_elementBtnId2)); }


        //Verifying that an element is not visible
        Assert.False(IsELementVisible(theButton));

    }
```

The idea is that user can call this method and pass the string from his/her test to validate the hidden element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `InvisibilityOfElementLocated` method in `ExpectedConditions` class coupled with `ElementExists` method. The idea is that if the element exists in the DOM but is still not visible, it must be hidden :

```
By your_locator = By.Id("foo");
Assert.IsTrue(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(your_locator) && ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(your_locator));
```

Comment: InvisibilityOfElementLocated wil check if  element is either invisible or not present
on the DOM. So, it doesn't mean that element is just hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Displayed` method to check the visibility of an element in a page.

If the element is visible in a page, then `theButton.Displayed` will return the value as true , else false will be written for the invisible element.

So, you can change your assertion as below

```
 Assert.IsFalse(button.Displayed);
```

Comment: So, if the button is displayed then this assertion will fail ?

Comment: Yeah.If the button is displayed, then button.Displayed value will be true. Here we are validating using Assert.IsFalse. So, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

This has been helpful for me. Works not just for checking invisibility but also for enable/not enabled, present/not present etc:

```
private enum ElementStatus{
        VISIBLITY,
        NOTVISIBLE,
        ENABLED,
        NOTENABLED,
        PRESENCE,
        ABSENT
    }
    private ElementStatus isElementVisible(WebDriver driver, By by,ElementStatus getStatus){
        try{
            if(getStatus.equals(ElementStatus.ENABLED)){
                if(driver.findElement(by).isEnabled())
                    return ElementStatus.ENABLED;
                return ElementStatus.NOTENABLED; 
            }
            if(getStatus.equals(ElementStatus.VISIBLITY)){
                if(driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed())
                    return ElementStatus.VISIBLE;
                return ElementStatus.NOTVISIBLE;
            }
            return ElementStatus.PRESENT;
        }catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException nse){
            return ElementStatus.ABSENT;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This bit of looks more robust and suitable to handle various outcomes. I need a bit of help understanding this thoroughly though, as highlighted below --   "private ElementStatus isElementVisible(WebDriver driver, By by,ElementStatus getStatus)" Am I supposed to declare her whether I am finding an element by Id/CssSelector/Xpath etc?

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated all solutions suggested here, but was faced with the challenge that (I should have mentioned we have angular pages as well), that sometimes the *Elements* which were supposed to be hidden were actually absent from *DOM*.
As I was not able to find elements and also I wanted the method to be reusable/scalable for other tests should I ever have to test another hidden button/element. This is what I did, and it is worth mentioning that I am using **Specflow** to parameterize my tests.

```
 public bool IsElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.FindElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

public void ThatButtonIsHidden(string p0)
    {               

        if (p0.ToLower().Trim() == "submit an order")
        {
        bool isBtnPresent = IsElementPresent(By.Id("btn1Id"));
        Assert.IsFalse(isBtnPresent);                
        }

        else if (p0.ToLower().Trim() == "validate order")
        {
            bool isBtnPresent = IsElementPresent(By.Id("btn2Id"));
            Assert.IsFalse(isBtnPresent);
        }                 


     }
```

Hope this helps. Works perfectly for me to handle the situation.